# One-way cross domain request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, cross-domain

I has to request to other domains in my app. There are two different situations. One is request data from remote site `requestData.action`, the other is post data to remote site( this doesn't need data returned) `feedBack.action`.

For the first one, I asked the remote server to modify their code to add a field `callback` and I use `jQuery.getJSON` to solve this problem.

Now questions is: **Has `feedBack.action` to be modified? If not, is my Ajax requestion can be recieved by the server?**

For example, if I listened for the user's behavior, and the user clicked a url, I send a feedback msg to feedBack.action by:

```
$.get(domain+"feedBack.action",{userId:id, time:curTime})//no callback function
```

Comment: Did you try it? You can, however, you can't avoid the console error that will happen unless you have it return valid javascript or nothing, and use jsonp, or even using an image element and returning a valid image.

Comment: if it is a cross domain request then that also has to be modified. another possible way is to checkout [access-control-allow-origin](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header) header

Comment: also have a look at [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: pretty sure you are trying to use jsonp as you're passing in a callback, so you would need to use `$.get(url, {data:data}, function(){ //callback }, 'jsonp');`

Comment: The first request IS a jsonp request. he's asking if the 2nd one needs to be jsonp since he doesn't need to do anything when it's complete and doesn't need it to return any data. Since it's just a GET request, he absolutely can just send it as a script or image request to avoid the error, as long as it returns a valid script or image, or if he just ignores the error that happens.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy the function is trivial, the real callback is in the data returned from the server, like:`cbFunc({data...})`. So the function `cbFunc` get called when the request url is loaded, and the function in `$.get` is never called. I tried this, I don't know why, but it is the truth.

Comment: @KevinB I can't test the request, I have no access to the remote server. So for your understanding the request could be sent to the server, yes? I am trying to simulate this logic in my local machine.

Comment: Yes, it can be sent to the remote server, it's just that, if you use $.get to do it, you will get an un-avoidable javascript error. to workaround that, you can send the request using an image, for example, `var img = new Image(); img.src = domain+"feedBack.action?userId="+id+"&time="+curTime;`. This will however cause a warning in the console warning that the wrong type of image was loaded, however that's far better than an error.

Comment: To completely avoid the error and the warning, you'd have to modify the remote server to either return absolutely nothing, a valid image, or valid JavaScript.

Comment: @KevinB The server does return nothing. But $.get will get an error. In this situation should I use `$.get(url,function(){},'jsonp')` to request a script? Or although there is an error, the server has received my request. And please make your comment an answer so I could accept it and help more people to find your valuable answer.

Comment: no, use `$.getScript(url)`. If it works the way i expect it to, i'll make it an answer. I've never actually used it in this way so i'm unsure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33671/discussion-between-zoujyjs-and-kevin-b)

Comment: OR you just use a regular form and post it to a hidden iframe. TADA! You sent data to another domain.